# TypeError: this.reload is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

My code:

```
Box = (function() {
  function Box(options) {
    this.id = options.id;
    $('#box-reload-' + this.id).click(function() {
      this.reload();
    });
  }

  Box.prototype.reload = function() {
    alert('test');
  };

  return Box;
})();
b = new Box({'id': '0'})
```

The click event is correctly registered, but when i click the reload button, i get this error:
`TypeError: this.reload is not a function`

How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` inside your `click` handler refers to the element `#box-reload-...` so use a `_this` variable as a reference to the correct scope, e.g.

```
Box = (function() {
  function Box(options) {
    var _this = this;
    this.id = options.id;
    $('#box-reload-' + this.id).click(function() {
      _this.reload();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

because this is the scope of the element, not the function. Simple test of a console will show you that

console.log(this);

define a variable outside to hold the scope

```
  function Box(options) {
    var that = this;
    this.id = options.id;
    $('#box-reload-' + this.id).click(function() {
      that.reload();
    });
  }
```